# Android Autocomplete Textview suggestion list is hidden on down arrow

Tags: android, keyboard, keyboard-events, autocompletetextview

I want to use an autocompletetextview in my project. The problem I am facing right now is that when the user presses the down arrow on the keyboard, which normally closes the keyboard, the suggestion list is dismissed. The keyboard is being closed the second time the user presses the down arrow.

I want the keyboard to close, when the user presses the down arrow. The suggestion list should stay visible. How can you achieve something like that?